# Javascript group and array recursively by multiple properties in a specific order

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, grouping

I'm building a grid component that will allow the user to do multiple row grouping.

The original data I'm working on is as such example for stock items:

```
let stock = [
    { order: "200", type: "production", qty: 200, item: "IT282" },
    { order: "200", type: "production", qty: 90, item: "IT283" },
    { order: "200", type: "customer", qty: 80, item: "IT102" },
    { order: "200", type: "production", qty: 110, item: "IT283" },
    { order: "200", type: "customer", qty: 130, item: "IT102" },
    { order: "200", type: "production", qty: 45, item: "IT233" },
    { order: "200", type: "stock", qty: 30, item: "IT282" },
    { order: "210", type: "production", qty: 300, item: "IT282" },
    { order: "210", type: "production", qty: 190, item: "IT283" },
    { order: "210", type: "customer", qty: 180, item: "IT102" },
    { order: "210", type: "production", qty: 210, item: "IT283" },
    { order: "210", type: "customer", qty: 230, item: "IT102" },
    { order: "210", type: "production", qty: 145, item: "IT233" },
    { order: "210", type: "stock", qty: 130, item: "IT282" }
];
```

What I need to accomplish is to be able to group that data using multiple fields in different orders, like the following results:

```
let result = groupBy(stock, ["order"]);

[
    {
        field: "order",
        value: "200",
        rows: [
            { order: "200", type: "production", qty: 200, item: "IT282" },
            { order: "200", type: "production", qty: 90, item: "IT283" },
            { order: "200", type: "customer", qty: 80, item: "IT102" },
            { order: "200", type: "production", qty: 110, item: "IT283" },
            { order: "200", type: "customer", qty: 130, item: "IT102" },
            { order: "200", type: "production", qty: 45, item: "IT233" },
            { order: "200", type: "stock", qty: 30, item: "IT282" }
        ]
    },
    {
        field: "order",
        value: "210",
        rows: [
            { order: "210", type: "production", qty: 300, item: "IT282" },
            { order: "210", type: "production", qty: 190, item: "IT283" },
            { order: "210", type: "customer", qty: 180, item: "IT102" },
            { order: "210", type: "production", qty: 210, item: "IT283" },
            { order: "210", type: "customer", qty: 230, item: "IT102" },
            { order: "210", type: "production", qty: 145, item: "IT233" },
            { order: "210", type: "stock", qty: 130, item: "IT282" }
        ]
    }
];

let result = groupBy(stock, ["item"]);

[
    {
        field: "item",
        value: "IT282",
        rows: [
            { order: "200", type: "production", qty: 200, item: "IT282" },
            { order: "200", type: "stock", qty: 30, item: "IT282" },
            { order: "210", type: "production", qty: 300, item: "IT282" },
            { order: "210", type: "stock", qty: 130, item: "IT282" }
        ]
    },
    {
        field: "item",
        value: "IT283",
        rows: [
            { order: "200", type: "production", qty: 90, item: "IT283" },
            { order: "200", type: "production", qty: 110, item: "IT283" },
            { order: "210", type: "production", qty: 190, item: "IT283" },
            { order: "210", type: "production", qty: 210, item: "IT283" }
        ]
    },
    {
        field: "item",
        value: "IT102",
        rows: [
            { order: "200", type: "customer", qty: 80, item: "IT102" },
            { order: "200", type: "customer", qty: 130, item: "IT102" },
            { order: "210", type: "customer", qty: 180, item: "IT102" },
            { order: "210", type: "customer", qty: 230, item: "IT102" }
        ]
    },
    {
        field: "item",
        value: "IT233",
        rows: [
            { order: "200", type: "production", qty: 45, item: "IT233" },
            { order: "210", type: "production", qty: 145, item: "IT233" }
        ]
    }
];

let result = groupBy(stock, ["order", "item"]);

[
    {
        field: "order",
        value: "200",
        rows: [
            {
                field: "item",
                value: "IT282",
                rows: [
                    {
                        order: "200",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 200,
                        item: "IT282"
                    },
                    { order: "200", type: "stock", qty: 30, item: "IT282" },
                    {
                        order: "210",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 300,
                        item: "IT282"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                field: "item",
                value: "IT283",
                rows: [
                    {
                        order: "200",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 90,
                        item: "IT283"
                    },
                    {
                        order: "200",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 110,
                        item: "IT283"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                field: "item",
                value: "IT102",
                rows: [
                    { order: "200", type: "customer", qty: 80, item: "IT102" },
                    { order: "200", type: "customer", qty: 130, item: "IT102" }
                ]
            },
            {
                field: "item",
                value: "IT233",
                rows: [
                    {
                        order: "200",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 45,
                        item: "IT233"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        field: "order",
        value: "210",
        rows: [
            {
                field: "item",
                value: "IT282",
                rows: [{ order: "210", type: "stock", qty: 130, item: "IT282" }]
            },
            {
                field: "item",
                value: "IT283",
                rows: [
                    {
                        order: "210",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 190,
                        item: "IT283"
                    },
                    {
                        order: "210",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 210,
                        item: "IT283"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                field: "item",
                value: "IT102",
                rows: [
                    { order: "210", type: "customer", qty: 180, item: "IT102" },
                    { order: "210", type: "customer", qty: 230, item: "IT102" }
                ]
            },
            {
                field: "item",
                value: "IT233",
                rows: [
                    {
                        order: "210",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 145,
                        item: "IT233"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

let result = groupBy(stock, ["item", "order"]);

[
    {
        field: "item",
        value: "IT282",
        rows: [
            {
                field: "order",
                value: "200",
                rows: [
                    {
                        order: "200",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 200,
                        item: "IT282"
                    },
                    { order: "200", type: "stock", qty: 30, item: "IT282" }
                ]
            },
            {
                field: "order",
                value: "210",
                rows: [
                    {
                        order: "210",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 300,
                        item: "IT282"
                    },
                    { order: "210", type: "stock", qty: 130, item: "IT282" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        field: "item",
        value: "IT283",
        rows: [
            {
                field: "order",
                value: "200",
                rows: [
                    {
                        order: "200",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 90,
                        item: "IT283"
                    },
                    {
                        order: "200",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 110,
                        item: "IT283"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                field: "order",
                value: "210",
                rows: [
                    {
                        order: "210",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 190,
                        item: "IT283"
                    },
                    {
                        order: "210",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 210,
                        item: "IT283"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        field: "item",
        value: "IT102",
        rows: [
            {
                field: "order",
                value: "200",
                rows: [
                    { order: "200", type: "customer", qty: 80, item: "IT102" },
                    { order: "200", type: "customer", qty: 130, item: "IT102" }
                ]
            },
            {
                field: "order",
                value: "210",
                rows: [
                    { order: "210", type: "customer", qty: 180, item: "IT102" },
                    { order: "210", type: "customer", qty: 230, item: "IT102" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        field: "item",
        value: "IT233",
        rows: [
            {
                field: "order",
                value: "200",
                rows: [
                    { order: "200", type: "production", qty: 45, item: "IT233" }
                ]
            },
            {
                field: "order",
                value: "210",
                rows: [
                    {
                        order: "210",
                        type: "production",
                        qty: 145,
                        item: "IT233"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

My group function would receive any array of items and group any number of array fields in any order.

As I want an ES6 based function, I'm today using the following `groupBy` function from [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890276/2697571) that works for a single pass, but I'm having difficulties nesting then together.

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
  groupBy = (rows, groups) => {
    if (groups.length === 0) return rows;

    return this.groupByField(rows, groups, 0);
  };

  groupByField = (rows, groups, index) => {
    if (index >= groups.length) return rows;

    let grouped = this.groupRows(rows, groups[index]);

    index++;
    let ret = [];

    grouped.rows.map(row => {
      ret.push(this.groupByField(row.rows, groups, index));
    });

    grouped.rows = ret;
    return grouped;
  };

  groupRows = (rows, field) => {
    return rows.reduce(function(groups, x) {
      let val = helper.getValueByFieldNameString(x.data, field);

      let found = groups.find(item => {
        return item.groupedValue === val;
      });

      if (!found) {
        let rows = [];
        rows.push(x);

        groups.push({
          groupedField: field,
          groupedValue: val,
          rows: rows
        });
      } else {
        found.rows.push(x);
      }

      return groups;
    }, []);
  };
```

Seems that the recursivity is not working properly.

Comment: Why did you delete the previous one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969950/javascript-group-array-recursively-by-multiple-properties-in-any-order

Comment: @Ankit, The previous one was wrong and I got 2 downvotes while editing it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can just make a function that groups an array using `reduce` and `Object.values`. Then after you group the array, if you have more fields to group by, call the function on each child `row` array. For example:

```js
let stock = [{ order: "200", type: "production", qty: 200, item: "IT282" },{ order: "200", type: "production", qty: 90, item: "IT283" },{ order: "200", type: "customer", qty: 80, item: "IT102" },{ order: "200", type: "production", qty: 110, item: "IT283" },{ order: "200", type: "customer", qty: 130, item: "IT102" },{ order: "200", type: "production", qty: 45, item: "IT233" },{ order: "200", type: "stock", qty: 30, item: "IT282" },{ order: "210", type: "production", qty: 300, item: "IT282" },{ order: "210", type: "production", qty: 190, item: "IT283" },{ order: "210", type: "customer", qty: 180, item: "IT102" },{ order: "210", type: "production", qty: 210, item: "IT283" },{ order: "210", type: "customer", qty: 230, item: "IT102" },{ order: "210", type: "production", qty: 145, item: "IT233" },{ order: "210", type: "stock", qty: 130, item: "IT282" }];

function groupBy(arr, fields) {
  let field = fields[0]               // one field at a time
  if (!field) return arr              
  let retArr = Object.values(
     arr.reduce((obj, current) => {
        if (!obj[current[field]]) obj[current[field]] = {field: field, value: current[field],rows: []}
        obj[current[field]].rows.push(current)
        return obj
     }, {}))
  
  // recurse for each child's rows if there are remaining fields
  if (fields.length){
      retArr.forEach(obj => {
          obj.count = obj.rows.length
          obj.rows = groupBy(obj.rows, fields.slice(1))
      })
  }
  return retArr
}

let result = groupBy(stock, ["order", "item"]);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for the post. I'm trying your posted code and for now it is working fine. I'm not stuck on buiding my table from the results.. How can I know, when rendering the rows, which colums to do rowSpan and for how many rows?

Comment: Hi @Mendes, there was actually a bug in that code, which I think I fixed. I also edited it to add a `count` to each item which will be the total of all descendants to a node, which is just the row length before recursing. I *think* that's the count you're after.

Comment: Very nice piece of code. Thanks @Mark for the version and attending my extra requirement.... Well done.

Comment: one more question. How can I add to each row the recursive fields that it grouped ? In example, the last example should show on each row that it is grouped by `field` and  `order`, as well as the number of elements. This is necessary to do colSpan's when building a result table using html. Thanks for helping!